# why I am not able to get access token?

Tags: php, curl, google-api, access-token

I am trying to get `access token`with this code but not getting any success.I have checked each and every curl operation ,every thing is fine.but still not able to get token.

[this is OAuth2 Guidlines from Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)

```
$data_string = "code=" . $_REQUEST['code'] . "&client_id=" . $client_id . "&client_secret=" . $client_secret . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect . "&grant_type=authorization_code";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//$data = json_decode($response);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: If you're not getting a token, everything isn't fine. Can you clarify what you mean by "not able to get a token"? The visitor is never redirected to your site? The redirection happens without a token? You see an exception or ? Is the response empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_string = "code=" . $_REQUEST['code'] . "&client_id=" . $client_id . "&client_secret=" . $client_secret . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect . "&grant_type=authorization_code";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, if you're using HTTPS in your URL, you must add in your code:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```